# Note taking app for mac

Tags: osx, note-taking

I can't remember the name of this specific piece of software..

It was a mac app, very lightweight and minimalistic.  When you opened it, you were given your last few notes, with a search bar at the top,which also served as a header/subject input field.  Things saved automatically.

I would love to find it again, if someone could give me a name.

Thanks.!

Comment: You will probably need much more information to let others help you.

Comment: im sure if people knew the app the information given is enough

Comment: @Ricky Your question is off-topic as it is written now. Please [edit] write a list of requirements for softwarethat you  need. Read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: As Jan pointed out: the scope of this site is to *recommend* software for *specific needs* (aka "requirements") – not to *identify* a given piece of software. So rephrasing your question accordingly has the chance of either exactly that product turning up in an answer, or even something being named that matches your needs even better. But as it is currently phrased, it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [NvAlt](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/) might suit your needs.

**Main feature**

one and only one text field is used to search and create notes, as well as for displaying the title of the current note.

**Usage**

type a few characters in the field, if one or more notes already exist matching the entered characters, they are displayed in nvAlt's main window. If not, hit enter and a new note is created, using the text you have entered as the note's title and file name.

NvAlt is a text file based app that let you either store your notes in a designated folder as text files or in a database (faster search). Choosing the folder method allows you to sync your notes between devices thanks to Dropbox or other services.

NvAlt is very powerful when used in combination with a system like [semantic notes](http://www.abolish.me/blog/semantic-notes) that allow to categorize notes depending on purpose for super fast search.